# Google cloud alert policies - how to get error message within email body/subject

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging, google-alerts

I have created a log based alert policy and I'm unable to include error message from logs in the alert notification email. Is there any way to include error message in alert email ?

I tried to setup a cloud function and then I have setup a policy on the logs for this function that trigger for the error severity. This works fine but what I can't do is get the error message in the email alert body. It shows details as " Log match condition fired for BigQuery with {project_id=myprojectid}" and summary doesn't contain any error message . Can someone help me setup alert with error message.